# Plone and document-viewer

Tags: plone, openoffice.org, libreoffice, documentviewer, docsplit

I'm working on Plone. I've successfully installed **[document-viewer](http://plone.org/products/document-viewer/)**: Now I have a very nice preview of uploaded pdfs.

The **problem** resides on **world and excel files previews**. As requirements says, I have to install OpenOffice or LibreOffice in order to obtain that result.

**What I have done to accomplish the goal:**

```
yum install openoffice.org-writer
yum install openoffice.org-calc
```

**The error I receive after I upload a file to test document-viewer:**

```
No office software found
```

Reading [this](https://github.com/documentcloud/docsplit/blob/master/lib/docsplit/pdf_extractor.rb) portion of code (from DocSplit, requirement for document-viewer) I can see that DocSplit checks the existence of openoffice/libreoffice installation in (line 57):

```
  /usr/lib/libreoffice
  /usr/lib64/libreoffice
  /opt/libreoffice
  /usr/lib/openoffice
  /usr/lib64/openoffice
  /opt/openoffice.org3
  /app/vendor/libreoffice
```

My OpenOffice installation is situated in "/usr/lib64/openoffice.org". Could this be the problem? If not, what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Well, you could try a symlink: `ln -s /usr/lib64/openoffice.org /opt/openoffice.org3` and see if that helps. (Package management should not touch `/opt/`, that's why I'm choosing that out of the seven paths you list.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ulrich Schwarz suggested:

```
**ln -s /usr/lib64/openoffice.org /opt/openoffice.org3**
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (the equivalent with you package manager):

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems graphicsmagick poppler-utils openoffice.org openoffice.org-java-common
```

and then:

```
sudo gem install docsplit
```

That's what we install on CI as you can see in the [package configuration](https://github.com/collective/collective.documentviewer/blob/master/.travis.yml).